# my mp3 doesn't play?

Tags: javascript, mp3

this is the code:

```
 var colors = ['red','green','yellow','blue'],
      tone1 = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3'),
      tone2 = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3'),
      tone3 = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3'),
      tone4 = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3'),
      buzz  = new Audio('../sounds/errorbuzz.mp3');
```

so all the tone1-4 play but the buzz mp3 which I saved doesn't and it returns an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no
>   supported source was found.

Help?

Comment: Pretty obvious from the error that you arent pointing at your mp3 directory correctly. Where is the file stored?

Comment: They error says that the path you have provided is incorrect

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's pointing on correct directory

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this buy uploading the files on github and using raw git. don't know why localhost can't detect. but. please try using cdn.rawgit if you encounter this error. best of luck!